All side pot player muck. What happens to side pot
With primary and side pot 3 of 4 players muck their hands. Only player remaining is all in for primary pot only. All other players mucked, no one knows what order they mucked. After seeing all in players hand, all just threw their hands. What happens to side pot?

It would automatically go to the last player to fold who could claim the side pot. Depending on the rulesets they may not have to show cards to claim a pot of everyone else folded. When in doubt call a floor, but without question the last person to fold in the side pot is the only option here.

As already noted, the pot technically belongs to whichever player mucked last, if there's any way to determine that. But if that's really impossible, the fairest thing you can do is just have the players draw cards or rock-paper-scissors for it. Or you could just leave it in the pot as dead money for the next hand.
